# Generate XML and HTML Report from NUnit GUI

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, nunit

We are using `Nunit` as a unit testing framework for our automation project. And using `NUnit GUI` to run the test cases(To execute the test cases in local). And we have developed a webapplication(making use of NUnit Core dll) to execute the test cases(Concurrent User's can run the test cases). 
1. `For Webapp` - We are generating an XML file and Creating XSLT's to generate HTML report(And this report sent via email to set of user's)
2. `For NUnit GUI` - Is there any way to generate an xml file for each test cases. So that I can create XSLT's to generate HTML report or Is there any open source tool to do the job easier?
We are using Visual Studio 2010

Answer (score 0):

The gui allows you to save an xml file of the most recent test results. Use Tools | Save Results as XML.

Comment: Based on ur answer the user needs to generate the xml every time..My expectation is like, after executing the test case from the Nunit GUI, I want to send an email automatically to the user

Comment: Is there any way to do that...I'm fine with any open source tool as well